# In MySQL master-slave configuration, ignoring tables with a large amount of data

Tags: mysql, master-slave

In MySQL master-slave synchronization, we configured the ignore table because of the performance problem of the slave. However, since the configuration is configured on the slave, when the host writes data in large quantities, will the data be synchronized to the slave and then filtered by the slave? In fact, if you ignore the table configuration, will the performance improvement be minimal? Or does it mean that when this data is written to the host, the ignore table information of the slave is read? Data transmission will not occur, which can greatly reduce the load of the slave? After all, I configure the ignore table to avoid the performance problems of the slave. If a large amount of data is written, the slave can't carry it.

Comment: What is your bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new database; I'll call it `NoRepl`
2. Put `binlog-ignore-db=NoRepl` on the Primary.
3. Move that big table into the database `NoRepl`.

That way, the filtering will occur much sooner -- thereby not clogging up replication either on the Replica or in the Primary's binlog.

If you are using Primary-Primary or you have another Replica that *does want* to see this table, then my suggestion will not work.

Comment: Your solution is suitable for those newly built databases. I may not be able to do so because business data is constantly written to the master database in my online database. This scheme cannot be realized without shutdown and maintenance.

Comment: @mxg89 - It would be a brief shutdown.  What do you do when a storm comes through and kills the power or the network connection?

Comment: If the database is just a database, your scheme is great. But many programs in my online database are calling. If you want to change it, the risk is too great. Front end and back-end developers may not be able to achieve this function.